# React Dev Tools can edit props even if in production build

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want users to use React dev tools but I want to prevent them from modifying or editing the states and props.

Here is the uneditable props.

[image]

But I get this.
**I want this to be grayed out and become uneditable.**

[image]

My website is running in production mode.

[image]